# Problem setting in Dual Monitor. can configure the "Primary Display" Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, monitor

In this case i use laptop as my source and another monitor that i want to be like the "Primary Monitor"

- Monitor 1 : My Laptop
- Monitor 2 : External Monitor
- Primary Monitor : External Monitor

this problem only happened when i move Monitor 1 to the right and and monitor 2 to the left .

[image]

The problem is that monitor 2 isnt be like the "Primary Monitor" the Desktops icon is on monitor 1 (this only happen when Monitor 1 is on the left of Monitor 2 ). When i open some apps it automatically open on monitor 1 not 2.

How do i fix this ?